# AttributeError: 'AliensInvasion' object has no attribute 'screen'. Python Crash Course game

Tags: python, attributeerror

I've got a problem that I can't really understand.
I've got a class as follows:

```
class AliensInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise a game and create game window
        pygame.init()

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Frame rate(FPS)

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # Import Settings
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Aliens Absurd")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/prabhu/Documents/Projects/alien-absurd/alien.py", line 52, in
<module>
    ai = AliensInvasion()   File "/home/prabhu/Documents/Projects/alien-absurd/alien.py", line 13, in
 __init__
     self.ship = Ship(self)   File "/home/prabhu/Documents/Projects/alien-absurd/ship.py", line 9, in
 __init__
     self.screen = ai_game.screen AttributeError: 'AliensInvasion' object has no attribute 'screen'
```

I don’t understand how the error occurs as I have got the screen attribute.

Maybe the problem occurs in the **init** method of my Ship class:

```
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """ Init the ship and adding start position """ 
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        

       #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship-al-abs.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

       #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen 
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
```

I'm doing all the code according to the "Python Crash Course" book.
Any help or suggestion are welcome.

Comment: You're calling `Ship()` _before_ setting `self.screen = ...`.

Comment: If it helps, you can see the code as it should look at the end of each main section in the chapter [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_3e/tree/main/chapter_12). For example, here's what the code should look like [at this point](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_3e/blob/main/chapter_12/adding_ship_image/alien_invasion.py#L22) in Chapter 12.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to place:

```py
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
```

before

```py
self.ship = Ship(self)
```

Exactly as John Gordon replied.